# C++ file handling opening

Tags: c++

`while (file.read((char *)&vg, sizeof(vg)))`  what is significance of  'char' over here?
 I do not know the why do we use 'char' while reading text from 'dat' file in c++
programming.

Comment: Welcome on SO! Please show a [minimal complete and verifiable example (MVCE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can understand this code. Also, show what you have researched so far.

Comment: What would you like to use instead?

Comment: You should get together with your classmate [yogendra pratap singh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842937/insert-record-in-binary-data-file) and talk with the instructor.  Looks like your instructor needs to clarify some concepts.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Insert record in binary data file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842937/insert-record-in-binary-data-file)

Answer (score 1):

I try to answer this even w/o a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), assuming that `file` is a [`std::istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream)
 (including a class derived from that).

The member [`std::istream::read(char_type*, std::streamsize)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) takes as first argument a `std::istream::char_type*` = `char*`. The C-style syntax

```
(char*)(ptr)
```

casts `ptr` to a pointer to `char`. In this case, the address of `vg` is reinterpreted as the address to an array of `char`. This cast is necessary so that `read()` can be called. A `char` is used here to hold a byte: the code reads from file and writes the object `vg` byte by byte.

Comment: Could the downvoter please care to elaborate what can be improved?

Comment: @RickAstley Are you trying to say that you can't write to dereferenced `char *` when aliasing other types with it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you can but you might write to padding bytes etc. Although that has nothing to do with strict aliasing, my bad there, you're correct.

Comment: Don't see why this was downvoted. Didn't even read it (due to the negative score) before writing my answer, which is unfortunate as I think we've ended up saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `file` is a `std::fstream`, [that function `read` expects a `char*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read), which means "a buffer of bytes into which I can read the value of the bytes from the file".

You didn't show a proper testcase, but we must assume that `vg` is not a buffer of bytes, but actually some object (like, perhaps, an integer). By casting a `VgsType*` to `char*`, you allow the `read` function to continue *as if* it were operating on the underlying bytes that make up `vg`.

Note that sometimes this is logically unsafe; it depends on what `vg` is. However, the actual cast to `char*` is valid because the standard specifically permits it as a way to inspect the byte representation of an object.

Answer (score -1):

The following syntax `(char*)` it's a C style cast to `char*`. So it's taking the address of vg by doing `&vg` and converting it to a `char*`. 
The read function must need an argument of type `char*` or a type that can be implicitly convertible to `char*`.

It is generally better to use [static_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) instead. 
Also I would try to read from file without needing to cast as general practice(as not all types can be casted to other types), that should be possible using the standard library streams.

Comment: And why is the cast there? That's what OP is asking.

Comment: I cannot directly answer to that without knowing the signature of the read function.

Comment: Exactly, so don't answer yet.

Comment: I think I explained why the significance of `char` which is the question...