# Insert record in binary data file

Tags: c++

In C++ binary file handling what does the syntax `(file.read((char *)&vg, sizeof(vg)))` mean?

Comment: Read takes a `char*` pointer as a pointer to where the bytes go.  It's using `char` as a synonym for "byte".  The `vg` is the buffer or structure which will be populated by the read.  The `sizeof(vg)` tells file.read how many bytes to read.  This kind of pattern is very fragile, because it has platform and compiler dependencies.  Binary files made this way may not be portable to other platforms, or even amongst other compilers on the same platform.

Comment: @yogendra : You'd better start by reading a good C++ book first! Then you'll realize that you can answer yourself this question... Cheers! :)

Comment: BTW, your question has nothing to do with insertion.  It is about reading.  Two different topics.

Comment: I recommend you talk with your classmate, [Pawan Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842016/c-file-handling-opening)

Comment: This is close, but not duplicate of [C++ file handling opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842016/c-file-handling-opening).

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is casting the array "vg" to a char pointer. sizeof(vg) returns the size of the array in bytes. A C++ way to do this would be

```
std::array<int, 10> vg{};
file.read(static_cast<char*>(vg.begin()), vg.size());
```

Comment: Not quite. `vg.size()` will be the number of elements in `vg`, 10, not the number of bytes to be read, `10 * sizeof (int)`.